# How to fix ambiguous column issue in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I made a global scope to get me data only with column status = 1. it worked fine. but I faced this issue in my code and I didn't know how to solve this issue:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052
>   Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `items`.*,
>   `item_orders`.`order_id` as `pivot_order_id`, `item_orders`.`item_id`
>   as `pivot_item_id`, `item_orders`.`quantity` as `pivot_quantity` from
>   `items` inner join `item_orders` on `items`.`id` =
>   `item_orders`.`item_id` where `item_orders`.`order_id` = 1 and
>   `status` = 1 order by `id` desc)",

This is my code :

```
$order =  Order::find($id);

       if (is_null($order) || empty($order))
           return ResponseHelper::customizedResponse(false,'4500','No Order is available');

       $user =$order->user_id;

       $place = Place::where('id',$order->place_id)->first();

       $orderItems = ItemOrder::where('order_id',$order->id)->get()->toArray();

       $orderArray = [];
        $itemQ = [];
       foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem)
       {
           $orderArray[] =$orderItem['item_id'];
           $itemQ[] = $orderItem['quantity'];
       }

        $items = Item::whereIn('id',$orderArray)->get();

        $itemP = [];
        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            $itemP[]= $item->price;
        }

        $totalItem = array_map(function ($price,$quantity){
            return $price * $quantity;
        },$itemP , $itemQ );


        $total = array_sum($totalItem);
        $customer = User::find($user);

        $address = Address::where('user_id',$customer->id)->first();

       return response()->json(['order'=>$order,'place'=>$place,'items'=>$items,'customer'=>$customer,'address'=>$address,'total'=>$total]);
```

Global scope :

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if (str_contains(request()->route()->uri(),'api')) {

            $builder->where('status', '=', 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That means you have `status` in more than one table, you need to **specify the table' column by its table name**,

like this:

```php
$builder->where('item_orders.status', '=', 1);

// In your case: you can use your $model to get the table's name
$builder->where($model->getTable().".status", 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

A fully dynamic and built-in way is to use the `Eloquent\Model::qualifyColumn()` method.

```php
$builder->where($model->qualifyColumn('status'), 1);
```

Unfortunately, it's not static but there's a workaround based on a "trick" that Taylor recommends [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1436#issuecomment-18618393).

```php
$qualifiedStatusColumn = with(new ItemOrder)->qualifyColumn('status');

$builder->where($qualifiedStatusColumn, 1);
```

This is useful when you're building a join and you don't have an instance of a model handy.

This future-proofs your code in a couple ways:

1. If you change your table name, this still works. (It doesn't help with column name changes though.)
2. You may end up adding another table to your join that shares a column name with an existing table in the query. Using this technique avoids the exact situation in this question.